# Root Partition warning for *all* Unix systems

Tags: linux, macos, unix, nagios

I have Nagios monitoring the Root Partition on all my Unix systems (being Linux - both Gentoo and Debian-based - and one Mac Mini). I am also monitoring 4 NAS systems (3 QNAP, 1 Synology) and my VCentre appliance.

Nagios has suddenly presented me with Service Warnings for all these devices, claiming the disk space is running low, with identical values...

[image: Screengrab of Nagstamon]

I set up Nagios with NagioSQL using a service template, but here is the contents of the service config.

```
define service {
        #NAGIOSQL_CONFIG_NAME           services
        host_name                       BLURR-2,COSYFEET04a,ELUCIDRF,Laserbeak,LOGGER,MIRAGE,OUTBACK,QNAP1,QNAP2,QNAP3,Silverbolt,VCENTRE
        service_description             Root Partition
        servicegroups                   infrastructure
        use                             standard-service
        check_command                   check_local_disk!20%!10%!/
        icon_image                      root.png
        register                        1
}
```

...and here's the config for check_local_disk from commands.cfg...

```
define command {
        command_name                    check_local_disk
        command_line                    $USER1$/check_disk -w $ARG1$ -c $ARG2$ -p $ARG3$
        register                        1
}
```

Ideally, I don't want to have to resize partitions. In some cases (the Mac Mini, the NAS devices) I can't!

Is the Nagios check simply malfunctioning, am I just mis-using the Root Partition check or do I have a genuine problem brewing here, because I can't explain why all values are repeated - one of the VMs is a P2V, one is running Nagios itself, one is less than a month old!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You should make separate services for each host, so you can specify unique thresholds etc

2) You are using check_local_disk, which has no -H parameter, so in fact you are always checking the Nagios disk itself. You should check the disk on a remote host with check_nrpe -H remotehost -c check_disk -a '-w 20% -c 10% 
Check out http://nagios-plugins.org/doc/man/check_disk.html

Comment: Thanks for the hint - we found the problem and removed the entries in Nagiosql. Just a miscommunication here. Some problems are so simple!

Thanks for the advice on check_nrpe.